# Why the antiderivative contains 2?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-integration

I am starting learning complex analysis by myself. Here is the question I am trying to solve and its solution:

> [image]

But I do not understand why the antiderivative contains 2? and why we require the condition that "any simple closed curve does not pass through the origin" ?

Could someone explain this to me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $2$ is a mistake: the antiderivative is just $-1/z$.  The curve should not pass through the origin because $z=0$ is a singularity of $1/z^k$.

EDIT: Here is my solution to the question.

$$(z-w)^{2m} = \sum_{j=0}^{2m} {2m \choose j} z^j (-w)^{2m-j} $$
so by the Residue Theorem, if $C$ is a positively-oriented circle about the origin, and $2m \ge n-1$,
$$ \eqalign{0 &= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C f(z) (z-w)^{2m} \; dz = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{c_k}{2\pi i}\oint_C z^{-k} (z-w)^{2m} \; dz\cr &= \sum_{k=1}^n c_k {2m \choose k-1} (-w)^{2m-k+1}} $$
This is a polynomial in $w$ that is identically $0$, so its coefficients are all identically $0$, i.e. all $c_k = 0$.

Comment: Also, is the statement of Morera's theorem used correctly in case of $m=0$? the Morera statement that I know is not iff. The Morera statement conludes that $f(z)$ is analytic not zero.

Comment: The fact that if $f$ has an antiderivative in a region, the integral of $f$ around every closed curve in that region is $0$, is just the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.  It is not Morera's theorem.

Comment: These "solutions" don't make any sense to me.

Comment: Thanks for the edit!! :)

Comment: I am so confused about the relation between n and 2m in this problem, what was the relation actually? what is n actually?

Comment: According to my calculations, I see that we should have a summation outside the integral sign over k from 0 to n and a summation inside the integral sign over k from 0 to 2m. how did your summation changed to only one summation from 1 to n and not to $2m$? my confusion is only about the upper bound of the summation sign i.e., the $n.$

Comment: Should not $0\leq k - 1 \leq 2m$ for the binomial coefficient to be defined? i.e., $1 \leq k \leq 2m + 1$ i.e., $n = 2m +1$

Comment: $n$ is gjven in the problem statement.  We choose any $m$ so that $2m \ge n-1$.  That makes the binomial coefficients ${2m \choose k-1}$ all defined.  You do have a double summation, but only  one term survives for each $k$ because $\oint_C z^j\; dz = 0$ unless $j=-1$.

Comment: So there were no need for using Morera at all actually, right? or is it required t say that $f$ is analytic and then use the residue theorem? actually, I do not see any use of the residue theorem in your solution as well, right? or I am missing sth? I see you used the binomial theorem and then did some simplifications to adjust the summation index. Also, what was the need of specifying that $C$ is a positively oriented specifically $circle$ in the solution?

Comment: Yes, no need for Morera. It doesn't have to be a circle, if you use the residue theorem; of course if it is a circle, you could just do the integration explicitly.